# ffmpeg : error using image2 demuxer

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, mkv

From the [image2 demuxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) of ffmpeg documentation, creating an MKV file from a set of JPEG pictures seems simple.

But when I run :

```
ffmpeg -v debug -i 'img-%03d.jpeg' out.mkv
```

It fails and reports :

```
ffmpeg version 2.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 14 2014 17:40:58 with gcc 4.8 (Debian 4.8.2-15)
  configuration: --prefix=/media/DOWNLOAD/ip7000_new/.build/i486-linux-gnu/libroot --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-asm --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-network --disable-bsfs --disable-protocols --disable-yasm --enable-pic
  libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
  libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'img-%03d.jpeg'.
Reading option 'out.mkv' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option v (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file img-%03d.jpeg.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: img-%03d.jpeg.
No URL Protocols are registered. Missing call to av_register_all()?
    Last message repeated 4 times
[image2 @ 0xa7d0ce0] Could find no file with path 'img-%03d.jpeg' and index in the range 0-4
img-%03d.jpeg: No such file or directory
```

I tried with different releases of ffmpeg and behaviour is the same.
Running it with strace doesnot show any try to open some files, so surely I miss something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you add `--disable-protocols` (among other things)? File input is considered a [protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html). Without protocol support you can not input or output files.

You will have to re-compile `ffmpeg` with a more usable configuration. See [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, and Mint](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) if you need additional help, or you can simply get a build from the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page.

Comment: I disable things that I don't need in order to get a smaller library, but I did not notice that local file support is disable by disable-protocols. Thanks !